# Problema em função de tradução em python

Tags: python, funções, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo um código em python com várias funções pra usar em outros códigos, dentre elas eu fiz uma função de tradução, que voçê coloca um texto, e uma linguagem, e ela vai no google tradutor, coloca o texto lá, pega a tradução e retorna, porém, preciso que essa função funcione pra strings de multiplas linhas (as strings com aspas triplas """), e também preciso que ela seja mais rápida pra pegar a tradução, por que ela demora um pouco pra fazer isso, enfim, segue meu código abaixo:

```
def Translate(text, lang):
    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opt.add_argument("--headless")
    brw = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
    brw.get("https://translate.google.com")
    brw.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/c-wiz/div[5]/button').click()
    brw.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/c-wiz/div[2]/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(lang)
    brw.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/c-wiz/div[2]/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)
    brw.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/c-wiz[1]/span/span/div/textarea').send_keys(text)
    time.sleep(2)
    translated = brw.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ryNqvb').text
    return translated
```

Bibliotecas que eu usei:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Se eu tentar usar uma string de múltiplas linhas, ela só traduz a primeira linha

```
Translate("""Remember of this indexes
    index 0 = google extension (@gmail.com)
    index 1 = microsoft hotmail extension (@hotmail.com)
    index 2 = microsoft outlook extension (@outlook.com)
    index 3 = yahoo extension (@yahoo.com)""", "português")

# Faz parte de outra função essa string
# porém se eu rodar o código
>> Saída: Lembre-se desses indíces
```

Ele também demora pra pegar a tradução, queria saber como acelerar isso

Answer (score -2):

Para resolver o problema da lentidão, que acredito ser devido a forma que sua função está acessando o google translate (via browser headless), acho que o correto seria utilizar a API do google para essa finalidade. Um exemplo de uso pode ser encontrado no link:

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text?hl=pt-br#translate_translate_text-python

Acredito que passando o texto para essa API, deve, inclusive resolver o problema da tradução de somente 1 linha.

Comment: não tem uma api gratuita pra tradução? a api é paga (exige que crie uma conta de fauramento)?